# Firebase - insufficient permissions, even though I am project owner

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I am trying to [export Firebase user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) using the Firebase CLI by calling this command:
`firebase auth:export save_file.json --format=json --project=MyProjectName`

This returns the following error message:

```
Error: Authorization failed. This account is missing the following required permissions on project MyProject:

  firebase.projects.get
  firebaseauth.users.get
```

My account has *Owner* level permissions which has "Full access to all resources" according to the GCloud IAM settings page.

**How could an *Owner* account be missing the required permissions? And how do I get past this error to perform the export?**

I have confirmed that I am logged into the correct account in CLI. When I execute `firebase login` it returns `Already logged in as ****@gmail.com` which is the same account I have Owner level permissions for (and which is the account that created the project.)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting authorization failed during 'firebase deploy' even though I'm an owner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The command needs the project ID instead of the project name.**

The error makes it sound like a permissions issue (because technically it is--just not for the project I was intending to access), but the underlying cause is that the project argument needs to be the ID instead of the name.

So the command should have included `--project=myprojectid-1234` instead of `--project=MyProjectName`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to select project before you do the export call?

```
$ firebase use MyProject
$ firebase auth:export users.json --format=json

Exporting accounts to users.json
✔  Exported 1000 account(s) successfully.
✔  Exported 1000 account(s) successfully.
✔  Exported 1000 account(s) successfully.
```

Comment: I haven't tried this because it requires setting up a Firebase project directory which I don't want/need.